# Trying to upload pdfs to server

Tags: database, next.js, server, prisma

I'm trying to create a 'find a job' website(nextjs front and back). In regard to Cvs and coverletters, I have encountered a a huge hurdle. I initially thought I could send the Cvs(PDF) to the cloud, get the url and send that to the database as I couldn't store sensitive information in the database. Then I discovered I couldn't store sensitive information like people's cvs on the cloud either(cloudinary). I guess I have to find a way to sent the cv's to the server on my computer and then get a string, create a table for the cv and another for the coverletters in the database and send the info there. I am having problems uploading pdfs from the website I am building to the computer. I was wondering if there was an easier way, or at least, is the way I am trying to do it the way it's done?

I managed to upload the pdfs to the front end to the public folder(formidable and fs installed), then I changed the address to my server address: /User/myname/pdfs but that doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The first question you should ask yourself is what information you need to store. It sounds like you want to save the contents of someone's cv, so ideally, you would want to avoid storing the actual pdf documents unless you need them to be re-downloaded. It does make sense though that you may wish to upload the file and process / parse it on your server. In that case, you can send the pdf document in a POST directly to your Next.js backend and process it while it's in memory. I would try to do some compression here. A red flag is I would avoid using fs within Next.js unless you have a custom backend because most of the Next BaaS use edge or serverless, which won't save files and usually won't even allow you to edit the filesystem. So to break it down.

1. Upload a file with a form (input with type file)
2. On submit send a POST request to your Next.js API endpoint (application/x-www-form-urlencoded) and try compression
3. Receive the file and parse the data ([this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-parse) is a popular library for pdf parsing)
4. Store any necessary data and take extra care with personal information. for quick projects it's usually easiest to setup a Supabase instance with prisma or typeorm to handle the database. Supabse also can be used to upload files if needed.